# Your test Suite must contain at least one test ( Refuses to count expect as a test when it passes )

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

When I run my jest tests on my vue app, It produces an expected error when the test I wrote fails but if the test passes, instead of showing passed, it doesn't recognize it as a test and outputs Test suite failed to run                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Your test suite must contain at least one test.

My .spec.js file

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Home from '@/components/home';

const wrapper = shallowMount(Home);

describe('Home', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('img').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

I expect it to output test passed but it outputs Test suite failed to run                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Your test suite must contain at least one test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `describe(name, fn)` creates a block that groups together several
>   related tests

So your `describe` block should contain at least one `test`.

```
describe('Home', () => {
    test('should contain img', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('img').exists()).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, thank you. You've saved me from hours of suffering